# How is interpreted the difference between postgres buffers_alloc and sum of buffers_backend, buffers_clean, buffers_checkpoint?

Tags: postgresql, performance, buffer, postgresql-12, wal

When checking `pg_stat_bgwriter` in postgres, I am noticing that there is a difference between buffers_alloc and the sum of   buffers_backend, buffers_clean and buffers_checkpoint.

What could be assumed as a "good" percentage of `total buffers written = (buffers_backend + buffers_clean + buffers_checkpoint)` over `buffers_alloc` ?

Which settings should be tuned to optimise this percentage?

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-BGWRITER-VIEW) first, and if that doesn't answer the question then relate your question to what you read in the docs. Also, this may be version dependent, so what version?

Comment: The docs don't answer that question all that well. In fact the docs are not all that illuminating generally on how to interpret pg_stat_*

Comment: You may look at this website: https://dataegret.com/2017/03/deep-dive-into-postgres-stats-pg_stat_bgwriter/

Comment: Have written this post and used it to tune some settings. But would like to check if there is some way to not allocate too much buffers than the ones actually written.